# Questions about getting data from multiple places in excel

Tags: excel

I have three pivots I'm pulling data from that look like this:

```
Work completed pivot
DATE(start_time)    | userid    operation_id    Time estimated  Time Elapsed


Fault pivot
date(date_entered)  | userid    operation_id    Major   Minor

Paid hours pivot
for_day         | userid    Total
```

The time tracked for each operation is not present so I want to get an approximation by doing
hours_paid * (time_tracked_by_operation/time_tracked_for_all_operations) but I cannot figure out how to perform operations on multiple fields from a pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the easiest way to do this is to simply load all the totals in a separate sql query and then just query from that worksheet.